# Magento move through shell - after move index.php needed in urls

Tags: magento-1.9, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Strange issue, I do a backup of folder and database through shell. 
I setup the new test shop in a subfolder, change the url etc. All good. 
Cleared cache, did a reindex.

Weird issue, after the move I always need webshop/subfolder/**index.php**/bla otherwise I will get a 404. So suddenly the web rewrite is not working anymore? I also checked if the .htaccess is still there.

Anybody?

Comment: correct rewrite base ?

Comment: Hmm you got a point there, so if you use a sub folder you need to change the .htaccess and add the /subfolder to the rewritebase. Now it works